# Grunt watch with live reload notification

Tags: gruntjs, watch, livereload

I'm currently using grunt-contrib-watch which has livereload built in. This is working fine and on saving a file Chrome reloads page (with the help of live reload browser extension).

However there is sometimes a brief delay in reloading a page. Sometimes I'm left staring at a page not knowing whether it just hasn't reloaded yet or whether a LESS/CSS change hasn't worked. Is it possible to have some kind of notification (like a beep) to tell me when the page has been refreshed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Might want to take a look at [Grunt Notify](https://github.com/dylang/grunt-notify).

This allows you to set specific notifications for each task you are running and allows for a large amount of configuration.

Example task at the top of your grunt file:

```
grunt.initConfig({
    notify_hooks: {
      options: {
        enabled: true,
        max_js_hint_notifications: 5,
        title: 'Notifications'
      }
    },//other grunt tasks here
  });
```

Comment: This looks perfect thanks. At the moment I have it setup and it notifies me on warnings. I can't work out how to set it up to notify me on completion when there are no errors?

Comment: Have you tried with just the default settings, so just installing the module and then loading it to your grunt file? This should get the automatic notifications working correctly, then you can configure them afterwards

Comment: I have added an example in my task. This works for me on OSX 10.9.3 at the end of every grunt task.

Comment: Yes default settings seem only to produce a notification when there are warnings. No notification is given on completion with no errors.

Comment: Hmm, yea it seems that currently you can only configure it to show when the task fails. Can't help much more at the moment. If I remember/have time I will take a look tonight as am interested myself. Let me know if you figure it out

Comment: Will do, thanks. It looks possible to have "success" notifications from the documentation but following their examples hasn't worked for me so far.

Comment: Yea thats what I thought but couldn't seem to get it working either. Try creating a notify task called watch for example and then running notify:watch within your watch task.

Comment: I managed to get it working. The success notification was displaying when running grunt but not when watch was running. I added a notify task within the watch task to complete after live reload runs. You can [download my gruntfile](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3454522/Gruntfile.js) if that helps you.